# SyntaxError: Not all output, log and benchmark files of rule per_read_aggregate contain the same wildcards

Tags: python, bash, snakemake

I've been trying for hours to debug this error. could you please help identify what i'm missing?

here is the error i keep getting

```
SyntaxError:
Not all output, log and benchmark files of rule per_read_aggregate contain the same wildcards. This is crucial though, in order to avoid that two or more jobs write to the same file.
  File "/scripts/workflows/aggregate_per_reads_ONT/Snakefile.smk", line 14, in <module>
```

Here's the full snakemake file

```
configfile: "config/config.yaml"
configfile: "config/samples.yaml"

rule all:
    input: 
        expand("results/per_read_aggregate/{samples}/{samples}.5hmC_CpGs_aggregate_reads_stats.rds", samples=config["samples"]),
        expand("results/per_read_aggregate/{samples}/{samples}.5mC_CpGs_aggregate_reads_stats.rds", samples=config["samples"]),
        expand("results/per_read_aggregate/{samples}/{samples}.methylation_states_counts_5hmC_5mC_Unmeth.pdf", samples=config["samples"]),
        expand("results/per_read_aggregate/{samples}/{samples}.hist_nReads_5hmC_5mC_Unmeth.pdf", samples=config["samples"]),
        expand("results/per_read_aggregate/{samples}/{samples}.hist_mean_exp_mod_prob_5hmC_5mC_aggregate_reads_perCpG_sites.pdf", samples=config["samples"]),
        expand("results/per_read_aggregate/{samples}/{samples}.hist_mean_exp_5mC_prob_aggregate_reads_perCpG_sites.pdf", samples=config["samples"]),
        expand("results/per_read_aggregate/{samples}/{samples}.hist_mean_exp_5hmC_prob_aggregate_reads_perCpG_sites.pdf", samples=config["samples"])

rule per_read_aggregate:
    input:
        input_file_from_config=lambda wildcards: config["samples"][wildcards.samples]
    output:
        agg_5hmC_rds="results/per_read_aggregate/{samples}/{samples}.5hmC_CpGs_aggregate_reads_stats.rds",
        agg_5mC_rds="results/per_read_aggregate/{samples}/{samples}.5mC_CpGs_aggregate_reads_stats.rds",
        plt_meth_state="results/per_read_aggregate/{samples}/{samples}.methylation_states_counts_5hmC_5mC_Unmeth.pdf",
        hist_agg_nReads_pdf="results/per_read_aggregate/{samples}/{samples}.hist_nReads_5hmC_5mC_Unmeth.pdf",
        hist_agg_5hmC_5mC_pdf="results/per_read_aggregate/{samples}/{samples}.hist_mean_exp_mod_prob_5hmC_5mC_aggregate_reads_perCpG_sites.pdf",
        hist_agg_5mC_pdf="results/per_read_aggregate/{samples}/{samples}.hist_mean_exp_5mC_prob_aggregate_reads_perCpG_sites.pdf",
        hist_agg_5hmc_pdf="results/per_read_aggregate/{samples}/{samples}.hist_mean_exp_5hmC_prob_aggregate_reads_perCpG_sites.pdf"
    params:
        rscript_from_config=config["Rscript_config"]
    log:
        "logs/{rule}/{samples}/{samples}.log"
    shell:
        """
        Rscript {params.rscript_from_config} --input_file {input.input_file_from_config} --hmc_output_file {output.agg_5hmC_rds} --mc_output_file {output.agg_5mC_rds} --plot_meth_state {output.plt_meth_state} --plot_nReads {output.hist_agg_nReads_pdf} --plot_mean_exp_5mC_5hmC_prob {output.hist_agg_5hmC_5mC_pdf} --plot_mean_exp_5mC_prob {output.hist_agg_5mC_pdf} --plot_mean_exp_5hmC_prob {output.hist_agg_5hmc_pdf} 2> {log}
        """
onsuccess:
    shell("date '+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S' > time_end_Aggregate_per_read_stats_ONT.txt")
```

Here's how the sample.yaml look like

```
samples:
    sample1_N: /directory/sample1_N/per_read_modified_base_calls.txt
    sample1_T: /directory/sample1_T/per_read_modified_base_calls.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `log` directive contains an additional wildcard `{rule}` which is not present in the `output`:

```py
    log:
        "logs/{rule}/{samples}/{samples}.log"
```

Remove the `{rule}` wildcard and the error be resolved.

Comment: worked when i removed `{rule}` in log directive. thank you so much!